# Hosts file redirection (from domain to Google) doesn't work

Tags: redirect, hosts

I am trying redirection with the hosts file on Windows. Tried both Windows 7 and 10. As a test, I tried to redirect facebook.com to google.com. I got Google's IP by pinging and I have added the following to my hosts file:-

`142.241.41.79      facebook.com www.facebook.com`

But, when I try to access facebook.com from a browser, I get this -

[image: Facebook redirection error]

To test again, I tried adding engadget to the hosts file, like so -

`142.241.41.79      engadget.com www.engadget.com`

But then, I get this error:-

[image: Engadget redirection error]

**Things I have tried to fix this:-**

1. Used multiple browsers.
2. Cleared browser cache and ran flushdns multiple times.
3. Tried running an Apache Server with SSL and tried redirecting to the localhost instead of Google's IP. Interestingly this time around, engadget.com does redirect successfully, but, engadget.com/reviews throws an error saying - Resource was not found.
4. Tried adding different variants - `engadget.com*` and even tried them on separate lines.

**What I am trying to achieve:-**
**UPDATED**
I would love to redirect all facebook links, for example, including `facebook.com/facebook/` for example, and any other links on the main domain facebook to Google or for that matter any other domain including a localhost server running Apache.

Is this even possible with the hosts file, or should I try another route?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to achieve this through your hosts file.

Websites like Google & Facebook use multiple servers across multiple locations with different IP addresses, this means that, even if you were to edit your `/etc/hosts` file, your browser might use a different IP address depending on the time, the location, etc., to access the websites, therefore bypassing your rule.

This is because the internet runs on something called `DNS-servers` that translate domain names (like google.com and facebook.com) to numbers (1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8), Cloudflare has a good explanation on the basics surround DNS ([link](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-dns/)), but basically when you go to google.com a DNS-request gets send out and eventually a DNS-server responds with an IP-address corresponding with google.com.

Companies setup their own local DNS systems, and create policies that force their systems to send their DNS-requests to the local DNS-server, that way they can control and setup redirection rules even though the IP-addresses might change.

If want to actually see the DNS-requests (and responses), you can always use a program called Wireshark, it captures all network traffic in and out of your network card including DNS-requests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do understand that. But, it was just an example. What if I were to redirect it to a static IP address website of mine? I tried doing that too, but, errors similar to the ones in the original question keep popping up. Moreover, while being on the same connection, I am able to access Google using the IP for that session. But, the redirection to the same IP doesn't happen. Is there a workaround for that, if I were to simply redirect facebook or engadget to a static IP of mine?

Comment: It will cause problems surrounding your secure connection.

Comment: Yah, it has been. Is there an alternative for what I am trying to achieve here or a way to fix the SSL issues that popup? I have already tried running an Apache server with SSL and redirecting the sites to localhost, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: The proper solution for this is setting up a DNS server. I don't know of any other method that might do the same.

Comment: WIll a Bind server work? Or, are there other alternatives I should look into?

Comment: I don't know the scale of your setup, but if it's just SOHO you may want to look into [dnsmasq](https://wiki.debian.org/dnsmasq).
Alternatively, if you are using Windows servers for your environment, you can use their DNS service functionality.